# Prevent parent Modal toggle when clicking on child in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

In a Vue app, I have a button with a @click function ("detach button" in the code below). This button is inside an element that is itself clickable. Clicking on this parent triggers another @click function AND a Bootstrap modal toggle event.

When I click on the child button, it triggers both events (@click AND Modal toggle) of the parent element.

I have tried both @click.stop and @click.prevent on the child button, but it always triggers the events of the parent. How can I prevent triggering the parent logic?

Thanks for any help!

```
<tbody>
    <tr
      v-for="project in $store.state.projectlist"
      :key="project.id"
      class="custompointer"
      @click.stop="storeCurrentProfileProjectBinding(project)"
      data-bs-toggle="modal"
      data-bs-target="#editProjectModal"
    >
      <td>
        <div class="symbol symbol-40px">
          <img
            :src="project.clientlogo"
            class="h-50 align-self-center"
            alt=""
          />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>

        <div class="d-flex flex-row">
          <a
            href="#"
            class="text-dark fw-bold text-hover-primary fs-6"
          >{{ project.clientname }}</a>
          <div class="ms-1">
            <!--begin:detach button-->
            <a
              href="javascript:void(0)"
              class="text-hover-danger"
              @click.stop="detachFromThisProject(project)"
            >
            </a>
            <!--end:detach button-->
          </div>
        </div>

      </td>


    </tr>

  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put something in your link or set some size for it:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
      items: [{id: 1, clientname: 'a', clientlogo: 'https://picsum.photos/40'}, {id: 2, clientname: 'b', clientlogo: 'https://picsum.photos/42'}]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    detachFromThisProject(p) {
      console.log('child')
    },
    storeCurrentProfileProjectBinding(p) {
      console.log('parent')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr
      v-for="project in items"
      :key="project.id"
      class="custompointer"
      @click="storeCurrentProfileProjectBinding(project)"
      data-bs-toggle="modal"
      data-bs-target="#editProjectModal"
    >
      <td>
        <div class="symbol symbol-40px">
          <img
            :src="project.clientlogo"
            class="h-50 align-self-center"
            alt=""
          />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row">
          <a
            href="#"
            class="text-dark fw-bold text-hover-primary fs-6"
          >{{ project.clientname }}</a>
          <div class="ms-1">
            <!--begin:detach button-->
            <a
              href="javascript:void(0)"
              class="text-hover-danger"
              @click.stop="detachFromThisProject(project)"
            >detach
            </a>
            <!--end:detach button-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure I understand this solution. What does the "link" refer to here? In any case, I added the .self modifyer to the parent, so now the storeCurrentProfileProjectBinding() method does not trigger anymore when I click on the child button. BUT the bootstrap modal toggle still fires. So my problem is really to prevent the modal to open when clicking on the child button. I don't see how I could do this with a Vue click modifyer as we are talking about two different environments: Vue vs Bootstrap.